# Qwik Prod. Runtime Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, vite, qwik

In my static Qwik app (adapter), I use this function addCustomer

```
    export const addCustomer = server$(async (data) => {...
```

to perform some task in my MongoDB when click in a Btn

```
    <button onClick$={async () => {const resume = await addCustomer(customerRecord); ...}
```

, and everything works fine in development environment. So I pushed changes to production into Vercel host. Then when I use my function again it Fails giving me this error in browser console.

```
    Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.
```

HELP!

I tried with globalAction$(), they are globally available across the whole app. Think about it like a "public" action.

```
    export const useAddCustomer = globalAction$(async (data: any) => {...
```

It doesn't works in development neither in production.

Minimal reproduction. I create a new Qwik app, with react and static adapters. In header click link to visit Form route.

[Project Repository](https://github.com/Maikpwwq/qwik-ssg-modular-forms)

[Vercel Deployment](https://qwik-ndv3c8fj3-maikpwwq.vercel.app/)

[Vercel Project](https://vercel.com/maikpwwq/qwik-app/)

Comment: where is your mongoDB instance hosted? are you using HTTPS protocol?

Comment: I connect to MongoAtlas, in Cluster AWS / N. Virginia (us-east-1), using a .env variable `MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0...mongodb.net/nexasoft_customer?retryWrites=true&w=majority`